# Characters filter by property value in React.js

Tags: reactjs, filter

I'm a trying to build an app based on Rick and Morty api.
I want to filter characters by species.
I've created separate components for each species value
For example:
Human.js

```
export const Human = ({ match }) => {
  const { species } = match.params;
  const [characterFilters, setCharacterFilters] = useState([]);
  useEffect(() => {
    try {
      fetch('https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/character?species=human')
        .then((res) => res.json())
        .then((res) => setCharacterFilters(res))
        .catch((err) => console.log(err));
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e);
    }
  }, []);

  const { name, image } = characterFilters;

  return (
    <div>
      <h2>Name: {name}</h2>
      <div>
        <img alt={name} src={image}></img>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

In the characters file I've set the conditions based on select propery chosen

Characters.js

```
export const Characters = () => {
  const [characters, setCharacters] = useState();
  useEffect(() => {
    try {
      fetch(CHARACTERS_PAGE_URL)
        .then((res) => res.json())
        .then(({ results }) => {
          if (results && Array.isArray(results)) {
            setCharacters(results);
          }
        })
        .catch((err) => console.log(err));
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e);
    }
  }, []);

  const handleSpeciesChange = (e) => {
    console.log("[e.target.value]", e.target.value);
    switch (e.target.value) {
      case "human":
        return <Human />;
        break;
      case "alien":
        return <Alien />;
        break;
      case "unknown":
        return <Unknown />;
        break;
      default:
        return;
    }
  };

  const handleStatusChange = (e) => {
    switch (e.target.value) {
      case "alive":
        return <Human />;
        break;
      case "dead":
        return <Alien />;
        break;
      case "unknown":
        return <Unknown />;
        break;
      default:
        return;
    }
  };

  if (!characters) {
    return <Loading />;
  }

  return (
    <div className="p-4 font-mono text-green-500 ">
      <div className="flex flex-row">
        <div className="m-4 ">
          <label>Species</label>
          <select name="species" id="species" onChange={handleSpeciesChange}>
            <option value="all">all</option>
            <option value="human">human</option>
            <option value="alien">alien</option>
            <option value="unknown">unknown</option>
          </select>
        </div>
        <div className="m-4">
          <label>Status</label>
          <select name="status" id="status" onChange={handleStatusChange}>
            <option value="all">all</option>
            <option value="alive">alive</option>
            <option value="dead">dead</option>
            <option value="unknown">unknown</option>
          </select>
        </div>
        <div className="m-4">
          <label>Gender</label>
          <select name="gender" id="gender">
            <option value="all">all</option>
            <option value="female">female</option>
            <option value="male">male</option>
            <option value="genderless">genderless</option>
            <option value="unknown">unknown</option>
          </select>
        </div>
      </div>
      <h1 className="text-4xl">Characters</h1>
      <Pagination data={characters} pageLimit={5} />
      <div className="grid grid-flow-col grid-cols-5 grid-rows-4 gap-4">
        {characters.map((character) => (
          <div key={character.id}>
            <Character character={character} />
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

But I'm not getting filtered characters.
I'm new to React.
Please help me to understand, what am I doing wrong here?
Is there a possibility to created a common filter component that I would be able to apply for different properties filters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot return jsx from a callback

Make filters get stored and only render these values from the array:

```
export const Characters = () => {
  const [characters, setCharacters] = useState();
  const [ speciesFilter, setSpeciesFilter ] = useState('');
  const [ status, setStatus] = useState('');

  useEffect(() => {
    try {
      fetch(CHARACTERS_PAGE_URL)
        .then((res) => res.json())
        .then(({ results }) => {
          if (results && Array.isArray(results)) {
            setCharacters(results);
          }
        })
        .catch((err) => console.log(err));
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e);
    }
  }, []);

  const handleSpeciesChange = (e) => {
    console.log("[e.target.value]", e.target.value);
    setSpeciesFilter(e.target.value)
  };

  const handleStatusChange = (e) => {
    setStatus(e.target.value);
  };

  if (!characters) {
    return <Loading />;
  }

  let filteredCharacters = characters;

  if (speciesFilter) {
    filteredCharacters = filteredCharacters.filter(c => c.species === speciesFilter);
  }

 if (status ) {
    filteredCharacters = filteredCharacters.filter(c => c.status === status);
  }

  return (
    <div className="p-4 font-mono text-green-500 ">
      <div className="flex flex-row">
        <div className="m-4 ">
          <label>Species</label>
          <select name="species" id="species" onChange={handleSpeciesChange}>
            <option value="all">all</option>
            <option value="human">human</option>
            <option value="alien">alien</option>
            <option value="unknown">unknown</option>
          </select>
        </div>
        <div className="m-4">
          <label>Status</label>
          <select name="status" id="status" onChange={handleStatusChange}>
            <option value="all">all</option>
            <option value="alive">alive</option>
            <option value="dead">dead</option>
            <option value="unknown">unknown</option>
          </select>
        </div>
        <div className="m-4">
          <label>Gender</label>
          <select name="gender" id="gender">
            <option value="all">all</option>
            <option value="female">female</option>
            <option value="male">male</option>
            <option value="genderless">genderless</option>
            <option value="unknown">unknown</option>
          </select>
        </div>
      </div>
      <h1 className="text-4xl">Characters</h1>
      <Pagination data={characters} pageLimit={5} />
      <div className="grid grid-flow-col grid-cols-5 grid-rows-4 gap-4">
        {filteredCharacters.map((character) => (
          <div key={character.id}>
            <Character character={character} />
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

The above example uses a filter which can be improved

> what am I doing wrong here?

You are returning JSX from the callback, for example,

```
onChange={handleStatusChange}
```

Here you pass the function which will be passed the event for you to handle, the problem is, returning a component from this function doesn't do anything, it doesn't tell React to render the component you returned.

Instead, you can store the value from there in state, and do something accordingly, for example, filter the array using that value

> Is there a possibility to created a common filter component that I
> would be able to apply for different properties filters?

That can be done, by passing the characters to that component and the filter values

```
export const FilterCharacters = ({ characters, status, specie }) => {
  let filteredCharacters = characters;

  if (specie ) {
    filteredCharacters = filteredCharacters.filter(c => c.species === specie);
  }

 if (status ) {
    filteredCharacters = filteredCharacters.filter(c => c.status === status);
  }

  return filteredCharacters.map((character) => (
          <div key={character.id}>
            <Character character={character} />
          </div>
        ))
}
```

As for your Human and specific species components, it calls the API for filtered values, but I assume you already got all values initially, so you could only filter from there, if that's not the case, you could make Human more generic by passing the species and status, and querying the API with that values